# Use natural nodejs library in Meteor project

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp, meteor, npm

I need to use natural (https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural), a nodejs library inside a Meteor project.

If I install natural using npm inside my Meteor project, it throws a bunch of erros becouse certain aspects are incompatible: (Doctype HTML in html file headers, for example, which meteor doesn´t like much.)

Can anyone teach me how to turn natural in an meteor package or just tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try [this project](https://github.com/jonjamz/meteor-npm). I haven't tried it myself, but there are likely some leads there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package in Atmosphere (a collection of Meteor packages) https://atmospherejs.com/package/natural

To install packages from Atmosphere,
You will need meteorite:

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

install the package:

```
mrt add natural
```

run your project

```
mrt
```

Easy this time ;) Enjoy!